# Rectangular shape boxes in a container(div) are out of position when the number of boxes is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following is a 16 x 16 grid where the user literally are able to sketch on the boxes. I managed to make it all works finally. However, now the problem is that when I change the number of boxes in the function by inserting number in the function **createGrid()**, the sketch will be out of its position(currently, it is set to 16, but when I insert 30 for example it turns south). The main container that's holding the sketch is still there but the sketch is over the boxes. That's really weird. I tried changing few things in CSS. I think that there are hole in my knowledge and understanding on it and I hope any expert/advanced developers can give guidance. Thanks.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow');

// const rainbow = document.getElementsByClassName('rainbow');
let reset = document.getElementById('clear-button');
reset.addEventListener('click', clearGrid);


function createGrid(number) {
  makeRow(number);
  makeColumn(number);
  draw();
}

function makeRow(numberOfRow) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.classList.add('gridRow');
  }
}

function makeColumn(numberOfColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
      let column = document.createElement('div');
      rows[j].appendChild(column);
      column.classList.add('gridColumn');
    }
  }
}

//adds event listener to all divs with class "column"
//added in global scope to allow drawing on page load
//this refers to the element triggering the mouseover event listener
function draw() {
  let columns = document.getElementsByClassName("gridColumn");
  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    columns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
  }

  function changeColor() {
    let blue = document.getElementById('blue');
    let eraser = document.getElementById('eraser');
    let black = document.getElementById('black');
    let rainbow = document.getElementById('rainbow');

    if (blue.checked) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    } else if (eraser.checked) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'beige';
    } else if (black.checked) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    } else if (rainbow.checked) {
      let randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
      this.style.backgroundColor = '#' + randomColor;
    }
  }
}


//eraser function loops through all column divs and sets background to "" in DOM
function clearGrid() {
  let columns = document.getElementsByClassName("gridColumn");
  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    columns[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}

createGrid(16);
draw();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#header-title {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#setGridSize {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 12px;
}

#guide {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  ;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
}

.gridColumn {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid beige;
  margin: -1px 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.default {
  background: beige;
}

#button-container {
  margin: 3px;
}

#clear-button {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>DOM Manipulation and Events</title>
  <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header"> Let's sketch ! </h1>
  <div id="setGridSize">
    <p id="header-title"> 16 x 16 Grid </p>
    <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Size of Board" class="size-box">  -->
    <!-- <button id="submit" > Submit </button> -->
  </div>
  <!-- <p id="guide"> Enter a number between 2 to 99 </p> -->

  <div class="canvas">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <form id="button-container">
      <input type="radio" id="blue" name="pen" value="black-pen"><label for="blue-pen"> Blue </label>
      <input type="radio" id="eraser" name="pen" value="eraser"><label for="eraser"> Eraser </label>
      <input type="radio" id="black" name="pen" value="black-pen"> <label for="black"> Black </label>
      <input type="radio" id="rainbow" name="pen" value="black-pen"> <label for="rainbow"> Rainbow </label>
  </div>
  </form>
  <button id="clear-button"> Clear </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are a few things off.  While still investigating this, here are already a few observations: your main flex R/C container doesn't wrap. `.gridRow` has no CSS defined. Two errors in `<form>`: `<label for="blue-pen">` and a `</div>` outside the `<form>`

Comment: Found it: in your JS `rows[j].appendChild(column);` shoud read `rows[i]`. You were using the wrong counter variable. There are a few odd things in your CSS, but that's beside your question. I leave it at this... Okay, fixed sizes and not stretching your elements. I modified JS `function createGrid(rows, cols) { .. }` with params for easy testing. To name a few things.